# How can I use python to add index numbers for the data saved in the text file

Tags: python

If I have a data saved in a file, all of the data is in columns

```
 0
 0.0123561
 0.0167374
 0.0207323
 0.024217
 0.0262322
 0.0284942
 0.0319818
 0.0348647
 0.0386309
 0.0388755
 0.0401626
 0.0425592
```

and I have to add index numbers in the file as the example below up to the length of the file here (n), how it can be done using python

```
 1 0
 2 0.0123561
 3 0.0167374
 4 0.0207323
 5 0.024217
 6 0.0262322
 7 0.0284942
 8 0.0319818
 . 0.0348647
 . 0.0386309
 . 0.0388755
 . 0.0401626
 n 0.0425592
```

Comment: Please try something first. SO is not here to write your code for you.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I tried on my own thats why I am asking here, not asking you to write a code, if you cannot help someone try not to write such comments. I am not asking an answer specifically from you. I know this is a very basic task but I am very new to python and programming ....

Comment: If you post no code you will get no help - if I don't post that comment you and others will just do it again.

Comment: @KevinDTimm , donot comment then .. ... if someone has to help he/she will .... bye..

Comment: Sorry, but I'm going to comment every time I see a post that has no code - especially when a duplicate has been posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `enumerate` function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

For instance:

```
 with open("newfile.txt", "w") as output:
    for index, line in enumerate(open("myfile.txt")):
        output.write("%d %s" % (index + 1, value))
```

Comment: B Thank you very much your code worked really well, it made my work really easy .. I am really grateful to you...